# How To select any quantity and it's value get's changed?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic 3 and want to know about the code please help me out guy's.
I want to select any item and it's value get's changed subtotal may reflect's to it output.

**cart.ts**

```
private _values1 = [" 1 ", "2", " 3 "," 4 "," 5 "," 6 "];

  firstDropDownChanged(_values1: any) 
  {
    this.currentPrice = (parseInt(this.product.subtotal) * this._values1);
    console.log(this.currentPrice);
    this.product.subtotal =this.currentPrice;
    console.log(this.product._values1);
  }
```

**cart.html**

```
  <span style="font-size: 14px !important;">Qty:</span>   
  <select class="sel" (change)="firstDropDownChanged()">
  <option *ngFor='let v of _values1'>{{ v }}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: you are not passing the parameter `(_values1: any)`

Comment: you forgot to pass parameter in firstDropDownChanged

Comment: explain me i don't know actualy what am i doing..?it's emergency to be submit today..!

Comment: use `(ionChange)="abc($event)"` .

Comment: The answer provided code below will do what you want. You are missing the parameter that's being passed in. Also your emergency != our emergency.

Comment: i passed the parameter now, the issue is rather i want to show the data when we select to 1 then 1 data's subtotal should be shown if 2 is selected then it's addition with the 2 must be done and show to subtotal about 2 products total is subtotal you have to purchase in .so,above code is near by approach from my side been done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2-way data-binding using `[(ngModel)]` as

```
<select class="sel" (change)="firstDropDownChanged()" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
        <option *ngFor='let v of _values1' [ngValue]="v">{{ v }}</option>
 </select>
```

So, on every change of option, the current value of selected option will be in `selectedValue` variable. Use in `.ts` file as

```
firstDropDownChanged() {
   this.currentPrice = this.product.subtotal * this.selectedValue;
    console.log(this.currentPrice);
    this.product.subtotal =this.currentPrice;
  }
```

**[Stackblitz Demo using ngModel](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-value-change?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: @jayshah glad, it helped, please upvote and accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to pass the selected value using `$event.target.value` in your `firstDropDownChanged()` method like below

**component.ts**

```
private _values1 = [1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6];
 currentPrice = 10;
 product = {
   subtotal : 10,
   _values1 : 1
 }
  firstDropDownChanged(_values1: any) {
   this.currentPrice = this.product.subtotal * _values1;
    console.log(this.currentPrice);
    this.product.subtotal =this.currentPrice;
    console.log(this.product._values1);

  }
```

**component.html**

```
  <select class="sel" (change)="firstDropDownChanged($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor='let v of _values1'>{{ v }}</option>
      </select>
```

**[Here is stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmwx6j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: what error you are getting. please check the stackblitz

Comment: i want to multiply each index and want to show it's data to the page

Comment: Please share  your product object

Comment: Please check updated solution on stackblitz and question

Answer (score 0):

Try this in TS

```
    this.currentPrice = this._values1.map((value: number) => { 
      return parseInt(this.product.subtotal) * value 
    });
```

And in HTML add below in Select

```
(change)="firstDropDownChanged($event.target.value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this i hope it helps you out

**TS**

```
currentPrice: number = 0;
private _values1 = [" 1 ", "2", " 3 "," 4 "," 5 "," 6 "];

firstDropDownChanged(data: any) 
{
  this.currentPrice = +this.product.subtotal * +data.target.value;
  console.log(this.currentPrice);
  this.product.subtotal = this.currentPrice;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <select class="sel" (change)="firstDropDownChanged($event)">
    <option *ngFor='let v of _values1'>{{ v }}</option>
  </select>
```

let me know if it is working or not