# How to store and pass the value of Mat-Select using ngModel

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-select with two Options i.e a user can select whether he is an Individual Customer or Organizational Customer.
Now I want to pass the value of the selection to a service class. How can I do that.
I have a form which is displayed after the user selects an Option.After filling the form the user clicks on save and all the information of form is saved. With the info I also want to be able to save the mat-select option.
How can I do that.

```
<!-- Dropdown to Select Type of Customer -->
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Select Customer Type</mat-label>
<mat-select (onSelectionChange)="getCustType($event)">
<mat-option *ngFor="let obj of custType" (click)="getCustType(obj)" 
[value]="obj.value"> {{ obj.viewValue }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Typescript Code

```
 custType: any[] = [{ value: 'individual', viewValue: 'Individual Customer' }, { value: 'organizational', viewValue: 'Organizational Customer' }];
```

Typescript Function called on Save button click

```
  saveIndCustData() {
const savedIndCustomer = {
  agreementId: this.agreementId,
  prefix: this.prefix,
  nameType: this.indCustNameType,
  firstName: this.firstName,
  middleNAme: this.middleName,
  lastName: this.lastName,
  gender: this.gender,
  dateOfBirth: this.parseDate(this.dateOfBirth.toString()),
  citizenship: this.citizenship
};
this.savedIndCustomer.emit(savedIndCustomer);
}
```

I want to pass the value of mat-select in the above form how can I do that ?

Comment: Just add ngModel tag to mat-select 
`<mat-select (onSelectionChange)="getCustType($event)" [(ngModel)]="this.customerType">`

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350480/how-to-select-any-quantity-and-its-value-gets-changed/55350840#55350840 , And upvote the answer if helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add `[(ngModel)]="this.selectedCustomerType"` to `mat-select` tag, eg:

`<mat-select [(ngModel)]="this.selectedCustomerType" (onSelectionChange)="getCustType($event)">`

Then declare public variable `selectedCustomerType` in your *.component.ts file